# Needing help with identification of shower faucet

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

The shower is leaking in our bathroom and I know we need a new cartridge but the problem is that we can’t identify the brand. The only marks are a K41 on the green water pressure balance unit and a “M” on the cartridge (or what I would think is the cartridge).  We’re just stuck and now sure how to proceed. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7JvI.jpg)
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: M stands for Moen

Comment: I thought that as well but I cannot find anything remotely close to looking like the pics I shared 

Comment: The only thing I found matching K41 and shower  [theres no access to](https://www.kantarzoglou.gr/en/plumbing-materials/k41-3-settings-shower-head40441.html).  Perhaps you can send them a message.  In the terminology here, it would probably be called a mixer rather than a tap/faucet.

Comment: Showing a picture of the *trim*, i.e., handle(s) and face plate, will likely help others identify. Also, there are often maker's marks on the trim pieces.

Comment: Whether M means Moen or not (I'm not convinced), get your parts to a real plumbing supply store and find the oldest guy behind the counter to ask.

Answer (score 1):

The Moen website helps with: "How to identify which cartridge your Moen one, two or three handle bathroom tub and/or shower uses by handle operation and color images of the various cartridges."

https://solutions.moen.com/Article_Library/Faucet_Cartridges%3A_Shower

"Still Not Finding What You're Looking For?

Contact Us or Call 1-800-BUY-MOEN

Non US?  Moen Canada | Other International Sites"